# Как выглядит конструкция IF…THEN в SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

Как мне выполнить IF...THEN в операторе SQL SELECT?

Например:

```
SELECT IF(Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y' ? 1 : 0) AS Saleable, * FROM Product
```

<sub>Перевод вопроса [How to perform an IF…THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/) [@Eric Labashosky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6522/)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор `CASE` является ближайшим аналогом `IF` в SQL и поддерживается во всех версиях SQL Server.

```
SELECT CAST(
    CASE
         WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y'
            THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS bit) as Saleable, *
FROM Product
```

Единственный случай, когда нужно использовать именно `CAST` — если   вам нужен результат в виде булевого значения; если вас устроит тип `int`, решение следующее:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y'
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END as Saleable, *
FROM Product
```

Оператор `CASE` можно внедрить в другой оператор `CASE` и даже включить в агрегированный объект.

SQL Server Denali (SQL Server 2012) добавляет оператор [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), также присутствующий в [access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php): (замечено [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select/6769805#6769805))

```
SELECT IIF(Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y', 1, 0) as Selable, * from Product
```

<sub>Перевод ответа [How to perform an IF…THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63480/564240) [@Darrel Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819/).</sub>